# Add class attribute in Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm using `CPT` library and I don't understand how can I add the `class` attribute on a single input field, I create all the post input as array item:

```
array( 
    'label' => esc_html__( 'Property Structure Type', 'zoacres' ),
    'desc'  => esc_html__( 'Choose related structure type of this property. You can manage property structure type settings at Theme Options -> Property Settings -> Property General -> Property Structure Types', 'zoacres' ), 
    'id'    => $prefix.'structures',
    'tab'   => esc_html__( 'Property Details', 'zoacres' ),
    'type'  => 'text',
    'options'   => $property_structures_arr,
    'attributes' => array(
         'class' => 'main-container'
     )
),
```

essentially the code above create a text field, but I want add the class `main-container` to that input, seems that `attributes` is not the way to achieve this.

What I did wrong?

official documentation: http://codex.pluginize.com/cptui/v1.5.0/package-CPTUI.Taxonomies.html

Comment: `$attributes` is part of the [labels array](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_labels/) and, AFAIK, doesn't have anything to do with the classes associated with input elements (BTW, are you talking about the front end or the back end?). Perhaps you can try [using a generator](https://generatewp.com/post-type/) to create the CPT?

Comment: WordPress does not have an API that accepts those arguments for a custom post type field. Are you using a framework or plugin for fields?

Comment: FWIW “Property Structure Types” really sounds like it should be a taxonomy.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I'm trying to customize the theme `zoacres`, and apparently this theme is based on `CPT`, I didn't found nothing in the documentation which explain how to add a custom class on the generated input. The author of the theme has added the array above using this function: `$property_box = new Custom_Add_Meta_Box`

Comment: Are you trying to add a class to the field on the edit screen, or the front end?

Comment: @JacobPeattie on the post edit, I also added the link for documentation in my question, I can't find anything about adding a class, could you help me?

Comment: @JacobPeattie also here the full code: https://pastebin.com/00biyCaK